Flutter x Android Studio SDK
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19045.5011], locale pt-BR)
• Flutter version 2.10.5 on channel stable at C:\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (2 years, 6 months ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
• Engine revision db49896cf2
• Dart version 3.5.4
• DevTools version 2.37.3
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Android\Sdk
• Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
X Android SDK file not found: C:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\35.0.0\aapt.
• Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/to/windows-android-setup for detailed instructions.
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
[√] VS Code (version 1.94.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\Roberto Jr\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.98.0
[√] Connected device (2 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19045.5011]
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 130.0.2849.46
[√] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
I'm trying to install flutter but fluttter doesn't find the file of the Android Studio SDK

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/mobile#configure-android-development from within Android Studio, you have to make sure you installed sdk version 35 and the parts listed on that page. If you can find the "SDK Manager Button", there are multiple tabs, the build tools it's not finding is on the 2nd tab

Try editing your question so it is easier to read and skim. For example consider using markdown for console outputs. Also try to make your title read like a question or a summary of the problem you're trying to solve.
